# How can I edit properties of multiple objects in a relatively shorter way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I'm changing visible states of many `labels` or `TextBoxes` depending on a choice from a `RadioButtonList`. As the page grows, these controls get longer and longer. I was thinking there must be a simpler and shorter way to do this but every solution I found led to longer pieces of code.

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
if (Tip == "Firma")
{
    fsFirma.Visible = true;
    txtGtip.Visible = false;
    lblGtip.Visible = false;
    lblFirmaGtip.Visible = false;
    txtFirmaGtip.Visible = false;
    lblFirmaInfo.Visible = true;
    lblGtipGrup.Visible = false;
    drpGtipGrup.Visible = false;
}
```

This type of a control happens for every 4 choices of the `RadioButtonList`.

6 out of 8 of these are set to `false`. Is there another syntax or method to assign `false` to them at once? Or is this the right way to do this? I think shorter code might not be best way all the time but still this guys look like they can be shortened a bit.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention I'm aware I can just set the default setting to `false` on asp code and manipulate needed ones as `true` but I'm asking to see other approaches too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `foreach` statement to iterate through a collection of controls, like this:

```
if (Tip == "Firma")
{
    foreach (Control item in yourDiv.Controls)
     {
        item.Visible = false;
     }
    fsFirma.Visible = true;
    lblFirmaInfo.Visible = true;
}
```

Suppose your `Div` element is like this:

```
<div id="yourDiv" runat="server">
   <%--your controls--%>
</div>
```